# How to change a database name in a query via a URL in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

i am trying to change my database name in my advanced editor query in power bi. I know i can create parameters with in the power bi desktop app and pass the different database with in it. I have done this and it works fine.

But what i am trying to do is when i give a user a link for example

[https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/DataSource="PowerBi_1"](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/DataSource=%22PowerBi_1%22)

how do i get the datasource name which is "PowerBi_1" and pass it into my advanced editor query which looks as follows

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database(".", "PowerBi_2", [Query="select *#(lf)from Customer"])
in
    Source
```

so i want to replace the Powerbi_2 with PowerBi_1

is this possible?

I tried searching and the only things i could find was to add parameters from "manage parameters" which i can already do. But i need it to be passed from the URL and automatically change the data source instead of manually changing it via "edit parameters"

i know you can use filter in your URL as https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/12345678-6418-4b47-ac7c-f8ac7791a0a7?filter=Customer/PostalCode eq '15012'

but this would only work on datasets. im not sure how to  do this for a database change in a query

Comment: No, changing the connection using an URL parameters is not possible.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov okay, is their a way that i could take the parameter from the URL and filter my parameter list that i have on a page?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "parameter list". Here is how URL filtering works - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters

Comment: i mean you know when you manually create parameters on the power bi desktop, if you enable the load you can add it as a filter on the page. So im thinking like in the URL above if i could filter that parameter. The above URL you would have to specify the table/column name

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could try is if you have a direct query and use the new feature of binding query parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters

Then you can set a filter with url to point to the database you need. Not sure how it would work - haven't tried it myself.

To expand on the idea a bit - you would need a table with database names in it. Then you would bind database column of that table to your query parameter and finally, use your url to set appropriate filter on this new table.

**EDIT:**

Scratch that, in the article I linked to, it says that direct query T-SQL is not supported. But if they were ;)...

Comment: ...if they were, our lives would be easier! :-) fingers crossed.

Comment: Makes you wonder - why announce such a huge feature and then make it only work with a small fraction of connections (Azure Data Explorer) ;).

Comment: Building up the appetite, I guess!